# Get existing offer id pysdk

Tags: python-sdk

I want to get the offer id based on the offer price and cancel that offer. How I can do that using python SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of existing offers submitted by a particular account with the following methods: *offers().for_seller(self.account_id)*

Example code:

```
offers = server.offers().for_seller(self.account_id).call()
offers = offers['_embedded']['records']
```

You will get following values:
*offer_id, offer_code, offer_amount, offer_price*

```
print(json.dumps(offers, indent = 4))
```

Next, you can import data to pandas dataframe using a loop. Now you are ready to retrieve values you're looking for using conditional statements, something like:

```
if offer_price == x:
    print(f"{offer_id})
```

To cancel the offer you will need to submit a transaction with a retrieved offer_id, but use amount equal to 0 (price is not important), for example:

```
transaction_builder.append_manage_sell_offer_op(selling_asset, selling_issuer, buying_asset, buying_issuer, '0.0', '1.0', offer_id)
```